# I try 'git svn clone http://host/svn/projectpath/ --trunk=trunk --branches=branches', but nothing download into my folder

Tags: git-svn

I try `git svn clone http://host/svn/projectpath/ --trunk=trunk --branches=branches`, but nothing download into my folder. `git svn clone http://host/svn/projectpath/trunk` works , but it can't manage branches.

Comment: Have you tried --stdlayout?  You don't specify a --tags.

Comment: I tried ---stdlayout and got the same result. I don't have tags folder.

Comment: The documentation doesn't include a trailing slash on the url, but I wouldn't expect that to make a difference.  Does it fail or work against a public repo?  It would either give us a test case to try, or it would tell that the problem is specific to the repo.  Does your repo require authentication?  What output are you getting (maybe with the --verbose flag)?

Comment: After ```W: Do not be alarmed at the above message git-svn is just searching aggressively for old history.
This may take a while on large repositories Checked through r ``` and stop. 
I have permission to access this repository